# Angular - Grid de PrimeNG no funciona

Tags: angular, grid, primeng

estoy intentando instalar Angular 12 con primeng y el primeflex, pero al momento de probar, no me andan los estilos, lo que hice fue:

```
npm install primeng --save 
npm install primeicons --save 
npm install primeflex --save
```

y después agregar en styles de angular.json con

```
"node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/md-light-indigo/theme.css",
"node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
"node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
"node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
```

En el html del componente:

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
    <div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">2</div>
    <div class="p-col">3</div>
</div>
```

Y se ve

[image: grid sin estilos]

Alguna idea de que pasa o que me falta instalar o agregar?

Answer (score 1):

No agregue los estilos en Angular.json, usa directamente el archivo de style.css global e importe la librería directamente desde los estilos globales de Angular

```
@import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/md-light-indigo/theme.css";
@import "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "../node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css";
```

Es otra manera de obtener los resultados de estilo de PrimeNG

Comment: Hola, acabo de probar lo que me has recomendado, pero no me ha funcionado.
Quite de angular.json las importaciones, y agregué los estilos al archivo .css de mi componente. Pero no muestra cambios.
Gracias por responder!

Comment: Bueno en ese caso haz varios pasos, primero, revisa que verdaderamente tengas la carpeta /primeng, para esto entra en node_modules y revisa allí, y después reinicia el server desde cero, osea vuelve con "ng serve -o" ya que el contenido en el archivo de angular.json solo se actualiza en cada compilación del server de desarrollo de angular

Comment: Si, en ese caso ya lo hice, reinicie el server y revise que exista y si esta.
Al parecer el error esta en la documentación, no existen las clases "p-grid", sino que directamente es "grid", al hacer el cambio me funcionó. Quizas te ayude en el futuro, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer el error esta en la documentación, no existen las clases "p-grid", sino que directamente es "grid", al hacer el cambio me funcionó.